# delay the commit of multiple sql queries

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012-express

so i have this wierd question.. as fare as i know, the database server got a validation process to only commit new data, when the data is all stored.

now my question is, can i run multiply sql queries, and delay the commit, until all queries have been run?

i got 600.000 new entries, i want to split into smaller sql "insert into" queries, so i don't have to start all over, if the SQL query fails.

so is there a way to do following

```
"DELAY COMMIT"
"INSERT INTO ...."
"INSERT INTO ...."
"INSERT INTO ...."
"INSERT INTO ...."
...
...
...
"INSERT INTO ...."
"COMMIT"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, use [begin and commit transaction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188929.aspx):

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
INSERT INTO ...
INSERT INTO ...
INSERT INTO ...
INSERT INTO ...
INSERT INTO ...
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Comment: Though depends what they mean by "start all over, if the SQL query fails.". They might need to roll back to a save point or they might find an error dooms the whole transaction and makes it uncommitable anyway.

Comment: hehe, well this actually did what i needed, i was pretty close though :P
thanks for the answer... i mark at as my answer when i get allowed to :)